# How to add a button to my node's Attribute Editor panel, which calls a method within that node?

Tags: c++, maya

I have a node that I'd like to add a button to within it's Attribute Editor panel, such that when the user clicks on said button, a method belonging to the node is called.

I have some knowledge of creating custom commands and making Attribute Editor templates, but I'm not sure how to specifically call a method within the node class (and not a custom registered command or MEL function), nor how to add a button with the C++ API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add buttons you need to use the corresponding MEL commands. You can use the `MGlobal::executeCommand` function to use them from C++.

See the documentation for the [button](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2017/CHS/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/button.html) command for how to create buttons with actions.

To call a method from your C++ code you need to create a command for it by implementing `MPxCommand` and registering your class with `MFnPlugin.registerCommand`. Then you can run it everwhere where MEL commands can be run.